# How to give padding inside time input without replacing clock icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a time input as you can see below

[image]

Here label and text are very close and not look well.In order to separate then I gave some padding-top to text but it also moved clock icon down on the right side.

[image]

How can I align the text without affecting that clock icon?

Padding added version is below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  .floating-input{
      padding-top: 17px;
      padding-left: 19px;
  }
  label {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 3px;
    pointer-events:none;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
<body>

                 <label>From</label>
                <input type="time" class="form-control w-25 floating-input" id="timeInput">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle`

Comment: Clock icon not shown in snippet.

Comment: it's actually in vertically middle.. label and input in two row

Comment: `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` didnt change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Chrome and Edge(Chromium) you can use the `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` pseudo element selector to position the clock icon to counteract the padding.

```css
label {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

input[type="time"].floating-input {
  padding-top: 17px;
  padding-left: 19px;
}

input[type="time"].floating-input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  position: relative;
  top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>

  <label>From</label>
  <input type="time" class="form-control w-25 floating-input" id="timeInput">
</body>

</html>
```